# JSON.parse unexpected token

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

i'm trying to pass from Android to javascript a json string that contains some html:

```
[
    {
        "introtext": "&lt;div&gt;<br><br>&lt;ul&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;a rel=\"nofollow\" href=\"http://redirect.viglink.com?key=11fe087258b6fc0532a5ccfc924805c0&amp;amp;u=http://www.ansa.it/web/notizie/rubriche/altrisport/2013/06/20/Magistris-Schwazer-Sorpreso-Napoli_8904212.html%23content-corpo\"&gt;salta direttamente al contenuto dell&apicarticolo&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;<br>&lt;li&gt;&lt;a rel=\"nofollow\" href=\"http://redirect.viglink.com?key=11fe087258b6fc0532a5ccfc924805c0&amp;amp;u=http://www.ansa.it/web/notizie/rubriche/altrisport/2013/06/20/Magistris-Schwazer-Sorpreso-Napoli_8904212.html%23correlati\"&gt;salta al contenuto correlato&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;<br>&lt;/ul&gt;<br>&lt;div&gt;&lt;a rel=\"nofollow\" href=\"http://redirect.viglink.com?key=11fe087258b6fc0532a5ccfc924805c0&amp;amp;u=javascript:document.location%2520=%2520document.location.pathname%2520+%2520&apic?idPhoto=&apic%2520+1\"&gt;&lt;img src=\"media/feedgator/images/monthly/2013/06/2_8b89e3983365ace9772b4ccfe99832ab.jpg\" alt=\"De Magistris:Schwazer?Sorpreso da Napoli\" title=\"\" /&gt;<br>&lt;/a&gt;<br><br>&lt;/div&gt;<br>&lt;div&gt;&lt;img src=\"media/feedgator/images/monthly/2013/06/2_8b89e3983365ace9772b4ccfe99832ab.jpg\" alt=\"De Magistris:Schwazer?Sorpreso da Napoli\" /&gt;<br> (ANSA) - NAPOLI, 20 GIU - &apic&apicLo invito a venire a Napoli e restera&apic sorpreso&apic&apic. Cosi&apic il sindaco di Napoli, Luigi de Magistris, replica alle parole del marciatore Alex Schwazer: &apic&apicSono altoatesino, mica napoletano&apic&apic, coinvolto in prima persona nell&apicinchiesta della Procura di Bolzano sul doping.&lt;p&gt;&apic&apicNoi - ha detto il sindaco - siamo paradiso e inferno, ma le emozioni che siamo in grado di regalare valgono molto di piu&apic di una statistica fondata sul Pil&apic&apic.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/div&gt;<br>&lt;/div&gt;",
        "id": "28262",
        "image": "./media/feedgator/images/monthly/2013/06/2_8b89e3983365ace9772b4ccfe99832ab.jpg",
        "title_categoria": "Sport",
        "title": "De Magistris:Schwazer?Sorpreso da Napoli",
        "catid": "11"
    },
    {
        "introtext": "&lt;div&gt;<br>&lt;p&gt;&lt;a rel=\"nofollow\" href=\"http://redirect.viglink.com?key=11fe087258b6fc0532a5ccfc924805c0&amp;amp;u=http://www.vocesport.com/portal/public/2013/06/NKOULU.jpg\"&gt;&lt;img title=\"NKOULU\" src=\"media/feedgator/images/monthly/2013/06/3_nkoulu-150x150.jpg\" alt=\"Il Napoli adesso tratta N&amp;rsquo;Koulou\" /&gt;<br>&lt;/a&gt;E&#146; un Napoli di chiara impronta francese quello che ha in mente Rafa Benitez. I due giocatori che il club partenopeo sta seguendo con grande attenzione sono Nicolas N&#146;Koulou e Maxime Gonalons, un tandem d&#146;Oltralpe per dare muscoli e fisicit&#2081;d una squadra votata al 4-2-3-1.&lt;/p&gt;<br>&lt;p&gt;N&#146;KOULOU &#150; In difesa non arriver&#2066;ami. Il Valencia ha cominciato ad opporre resistenza, Bigon ha fatto un passettino indietro e si &#36659;pan&gt;&lt;br /&gt;guardato intorno. L&#146;obiettivo ora &#34830;icolas N&#146;Koulou del Marsiglia, un camerunense seguito per settimane intere, avvicinato lo scorso aprile, ritenuto l&#146;interprete fedele d&#146;una idea di calcio nel quale convergono et&#2085; prospettive. In regia si punta tutto su Maxime Gonalons (24), giocatore che sintetizza le qualit&#2101;tili per appagare Benitez, l&#146;interditore che ha piede, che ha i giri giusti nel suo calcio, attraverso il quale far ripartire l&#146;azione assieme ad Inler o a Dzemaili.&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;<br>&lt;p&gt;fontE: corrieredellosport.it&lt;/p&gt;<br>...&lt;/div&gt;",
        "id": "28286",
        "image": "./media/feedgator/images/monthly/2013/06/3_nkoulu-150x150.jpg",
        "title_categoria": "Sport Locale",
        "title": "Il Napoli adesso tratta N&#146;Koulou",
        "catid": "13"
    },
    {
        "introtext": "&lt;p&gt;&lt;img style=\"border: 1px solid #cccccc; margin-right: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; float: left;\" alt=\"rivendesi tab\" src=\"images/r_news/rivendesi_tab.jpg\" height=\"187\" width=\"250\" /&gt;La rete Tablet comincia a prendere piede.. Il lavoro nelle mani di Zuwann Pisacane e Jack Turchi sta affrontando la prima prova.. Siamo in una versione beta e ci scusiamo per i disagi e le disconnessioni dalla rete.&lt;/p&gt;\r<br>&lt;p&gt;Il nostro &#34869;n progetto pilota che sta muovendo i primi passa da Salerno, una delle citt&#2096;i&#55618;&#56485;lle del sud Italia.&lt;/p&gt;\r<br>&lt;p&gt;La nostra speranza &#34852;i riuscire a diffondere la nostra soluzione in ogni dove e ad offrire gratuitamente a tutti notizie in tempo reale, annunci economici, servizi di utilit&#2976;Il tutto con estrema semplicit&#3004;/p&gt;\r<br>&lt;p&gt;Rivendesi Tablet is work in progress...&lt;/p&gt;",
        "id": "24693",
        "image": "./images/r_news/rivendesi_tab.jpg",
        "title_categoria": "R-NEWS",
        "title": "La rete RIVENDESI cresce...",
        "catid": "17"
    },
    {
        "introtext": "&lt;div&gt;<br><br>&lt;ul&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;a rel=\"nofollow\" href=\"http://redirect.viglink.com?key=11fe087258b6fc0532a5ccfc924805c0&amp;amp;u=http://www.ansa.it/web/notizie/rubriche/mondo/2013/06/21/Rousseff-convoca-gabinetto-crisi_8904913.html%23content-corpo\"&gt;salta direttamente al contenuto dell&apicarticolo&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;<br>&lt;li&gt;&lt;a rel=\"nofollow\" href=\"http://redirect.viglink.com?key=11fe087258b6fc0532a5ccfc924805c0&amp;amp;u=http://www.ansa.it/web/notizie/rubriche/mondo/2013/06/21/Rousseff-convoca-gabinetto-crisi_8904913.html%23correlati\"&gt;salta al contenuto correlato&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;<br>&lt;/ul&gt;<br>&lt;div&gt;&lt;a rel=\"nofollow\" href=\"http://redirect.viglink.com?key=11fe087258b6fc0532a5ccfc924805c0&amp;amp;u=javascript:document.location%2520=%2520document.location.pathname%2520+%2520&apic?idPhoto=&apic%2520+1\"&gt;&lt;img src=\"media/feedgator/images/monthly/2013/06/6_2c63e16587689844f01a4c5af81db9af.jpg\" alt=\"Rousseff convoca gabinetto di crisi\" title=\"\" /&gt;<br>&lt;/a&gt;<br><br>&lt;/div&gt;<br>&lt;div&gt;&lt;img src=\"media/feedgator/images/monthly/2013/06/6_2c63e16587689844f01a4c5af81db9af.jpg\" alt=\"Rousseff convoca gabinetto di crisi\" /&gt;<br> (ANSA) - RIO DE JANEIRO, 21 GIU - La presidente del Brasile, Dilma Rousseff, ha convocato venerd&#51245;attina alle 9:30 (le 14:30 in Italia) un gabinetto di crisi con i ministri pi&#55619;&#56745;cini, a seguito delle manifestazioni in tutto il paese. Lo hanno reso noto i siti dei tre principali giornali brasiliani (Globo, Folha de Sao Paolo, Estado de Sao Paulo).&lt;/div&gt;<br>&lt;/div&gt;",
        "id": "28282",
        "image": "./media/feedgator/images/monthly/2013/06/6_2c63e16587689844f01a4c5af81db9af.jpg",
        "title_categoria": "Politica",
        "title": "Rousseff convoca gabinetto di crisi",
        "catid": "19"
    },
    {
        "introtext": "&lt;div&gt;<br><br>&lt;ul&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;a rel=\"nofollow\" href=\"http://redirect.viglink.com?key=11fe087258b6fc0532a5ccfc924805c0&amp;amp;u=http://www.ansa.it/web/notizie/regioni/campania/2013/06/20/Benitez-arrivato-Napoli_8904259.html%23content-corpo\"&gt;salta direttamente al contenuto dell&apicarticolo&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;<br>&lt;li&gt;&lt;a rel=\"nofollow\" href=\"http://redirect.viglink.com?key=11fe087258b6fc0532a5ccfc924805c0&amp;amp;u=http://www.ansa.it/web/notizie/regioni/campania/2013/06/20/Benitez-arrivato-Napoli_8904259.html%23correlati\"&gt;salta al contenuto correlato&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;<br>&lt;/ul&gt;<br>&lt;div&gt;&lt;a rel=\"nofollow\" href=\"http://redirect.viglink.com?key=11fe087258b6fc0532a5ccfc924805c0&amp;amp;u=javascript:document.location%2520=%2520document.location.pathname%2520+%2520&apic?idPhoto=&apic%2520+1\"&gt;&lt;img src=\"media/feedgator/images/monthly/2013/06/4_622773c69ff82b97ed62f09dcdf1a320.jpg\" alt=\"Benitez e&apic arrivato a Napoli\" title=\"\" /&gt;<br>&lt;/a&gt;<br><br>&lt;/div&gt;<br>&lt;div&gt;&lt;img src=\"media/feedgator/images/monthly/2013/06/4_622773c69ff82b97ed62f09dcdf1a320.jpg\" alt=\"Benitez e&apic arrivato a Napoli\" /&gt;<br> (ANSA) - NAPOLI, 20 GIU - Rafael Benitez e&apic giunto in serata a Napoli, con un volo proveniente da Londra, e ha raggiunto lo storico hotel Vesuvio, sul lungomare partenopeo, dove ad attenderlo c&apicera un folto gruppo di fotografi e giornalisti. Il nuovo allenatore del Napoli sara&apic presentato ufficialmente domani, in una conferenza stampa programmata nel quartier generale azzurro, a Castel Volturno (Caserta), alle 17.&lt;/div&gt;<br>&lt;/div&gt;",
        "id": "28264",
        "image": "./media/feedgator/images/monthly/2013/06/4_622773c69ff82b97ed62f09dcdf1a320.jpg",
        "title_categoria": "Notizie Locali",
        "title": "Benitez e&apic arrivato a Napoli",
        "catid": "20"
    },
    {
        "introtext": "&lt;div&gt;<br><br>&lt;ul&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;a rel=\"nofollow\" href=\"http://redirect.viglink.com?key=11fe087258b6fc0532a5ccfc924805c0&amp;amp;u=http://www.ansa.it/web/notizie/rubriche/economia/2013/06/21/Borsa-Asia-giu-Fed-resiste-Tokyo_8905030.html%23content-corpo\"&gt;salta direttamente al contenuto dell&apicarticolo&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;<br>&lt;li&gt;&lt;a rel=\"nofollow\" href=\"http://redirect.viglink.com?key=11fe087258b6fc0532a5ccfc924805c0&amp;amp;u=http://www.ansa.it/web/notizie/rubriche/economia/2013/06/21/Borsa-Asia-giu-Fed-resiste-Tokyo_8905030.html%23correlati\"&gt;salta al contenuto correlato&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;<br>&lt;/ul&gt;<br>&lt;div&gt;&lt;a rel=\"nofollow\" href=\"http://redirect.viglink.com?key=11fe087258b6fc0532a5ccfc924805c0&amp;amp;u=javascript:document.location%2520=%2520document.location.pathname%2520+%2520&apic?idPhoto=&apic%2520+1\"&gt;&lt;img src=\"media/feedgator/images/monthly/2013/06/9_b6a96ee38ad6cc1995ed53a90bcf6a52.jpg\" alt=\"Borsa: Asia giu&apic con Fed, resiste Tokyo\" title=\"\" /&gt;<br>&lt;/a&gt;<br><br>&lt;/div&gt;<br>&lt;div&gt;&lt;img src=\"media/feedgator/images/monthly/2013/06/9_b6a96ee38ad6cc1995ed53a90bcf6a52.jpg\" alt=\"Borsa: Asia giu&apic con Fed, resiste Tokyo\" /&gt;<br> (ANSA) - MILANO, 21 GIU - Proseguono le vendite innescate dall&apicannuncio della Fed di chiudere il programma di acquisto di bond. Anche oggi sulle borse borse asiatiche ha dominato il segno rosso, con l&apiceccezione di Tokyo (+1,66%), rimbalzata grazie all&apicindebolimento dello yen. Scendono di oltre il 4% i tassi overnight in Cina, dopo le forti tensioni di ieri, grazie alle indiscrezioni che danno la banca centrale cinese disponibile a fornire liquidita&apic alle banche. Deboli Hong Kong e Sydney (-0,4%), male Seul (-1,5%).&lt;/div&gt;<br>&lt;/div&gt;",
        "id": "28287",
        "image": "./media/feedgator/images/monthly/2013/06/9_b6a96ee38ad6cc1995ed53a90bcf6a52.jpg",
        "title_categoria": "Economia",
        "title": "Borsa: Asia giu&apic con Fed, resiste Tokyo",
        "catid": "21"
    },
    {
        "introtext": "&lt;div&gt;<br><br>&lt;ul&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;a rel=\"nofollow\" href=\"http://redirect.viglink.com?key=11fe087258b6fc0532a5ccfc924805c0&amp;amp;u=http://www.ansa.it/web/notizie/rubriche/spettacolo/2013/06/20/Maldamore-coppia-inaffidabile_8903049.html%23content-corpo\"&gt;salta direttamente al contenuto dell&apicarticolo&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;<br>&lt;li&gt;&lt;a rel=\"nofollow\" href=\"http://redirect.viglink.com?key=11fe087258b6fc0532a5ccfc924805c0&amp;amp;u=http://www.ansa.it/web/notizie/rubriche/spettacolo/2013/06/20/Maldamore-coppia-inaffidabile_8903049.html%23correlati\"&gt;salta al contenuto correlato&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;<br>&lt;/ul&gt;<br>&lt;div&gt;&lt;a rel=\"nofollow\" href=\"http://redirect.viglink.com?key=11fe087258b6fc0532a5ccfc924805c0&amp;amp;u=javascript:document.location%2520=%2520document.location.pathname%2520+%2520&apic?idPhoto=&apic%2520+1\"&gt;&lt;img src=\"media/feedgator/images/monthly/2013/06/10_40e8a33b40ac20ce23f339b03b69037d.jpg\" alt=\"In &apicMaldamore&apic la coppia inaffidabile\" title=\"\" /&gt;<br>&lt;/a&gt;<br><br>&lt;/div&gt;<br>&lt;div&gt;&lt;img src=\"media/feedgator/images/monthly/2013/06/10_40e8a33b40ac20ce23f339b03b69037d.jpg\" alt=\"In &apicMaldamore&apic la coppia inaffidabile\" /&gt;<br> (ANSA) - TRENTO, 20 GIU - Sono in corso a Trento le riprese del film &apicMaldamore&apic di Angelo Longoni con Luca Zingaretti, Luisa Ranieri e Alessio Boni, prodotto da Italian Dreams Factory di Maria Grazia Cucinotta. &apic&apicIl film parla dell&apicinaffidabilita&apic della coppia, condizione che si puo&apic estendere anche agli italiani, popolo spesso inaffidabile&apic&apic, dice Longoni secondo cui &apic&apicancora oggi e&apic valido il concetto che &apicil privato e&apic politico&apic. Un comportamento scorretto nel privato si riflette in quello pubblico&apic&apic.&lt;/div&gt;<br>&lt;/div&gt;",
        "id": "28242",
        "image": "./media/feedgator/images/monthly/2013/06/10_40e8a33b40ac20ce23f339b03b69037d.jpg",
        "title_categoria": "Spettacolo",
        "title": "In &apicMaldamore&apic la coppia inaffidabile",
        "catid": "23"
    },
    {
        "introtext": "&lt;div&gt; &lt;a rel=\"nofollow\" href=\"http://www.solosalerno.it/2013/06/20/grassi-arriva-lannuncio-della-societa-daro-lanima-per-questa-maglia/\" title=\"Grassi, arriva l&apicannuncio della societ&#3744;&amp;quot;Dar&#55874;&#57127;anima per questa maglia&amp;quot;\"&gt;&lt;img title=\"Grassi, arriva l&apicannuncio della societ&amp;Atilde;&amp;nbsp;: &amp;quot;Dar&amp;Atilde;&amp;sup2; l&apicanima per questa maglia&amp;quot;\" src=\"media/feedgator/images/monthly/2013/06/7_grassi-pontedera.jpg\" alt=\"Grassi, arriva l&apicannuncio della societ&amp;Atilde;&amp;nbsp;: &amp;quot;Dar&amp;Atilde;&amp;sup2; l&apicanima per questa maglia&amp;quot;\" /&gt;<br>&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/div&gt; &lt;br /&gt; &lt;a href=\"http://www.solosalerno.it/2013/06/14/il-neogranata-grassi-a-solosalerno-lotito-mi-ha-detto-che-vuol-vincere-concorrenza-non-mi-spaventa/grassi-pontedera/\" rel=\"nofollow\"&gt;&lt;img alt=\"grassi pontedera\" src=\"media/feedgator/images/monthly/2013/06/7_grassi-pontedera.jpg\" /&gt;<br>&lt;/a&gt;Mancava solo la formalit&#2084;ella firma in calce al contratto biennale, ma &lt;strong&gt;Luigi Grassi&lt;/strong&gt; gi&#2084;a una settimana poteva considerarsi a tutti gli effetti un calciatore della Salernitana. In giornata &#34849;rrivato anche l&apicannuncio ufficiale sul sito del sodalizio di Via Allende, che ha raccolto la gioia&#160; dell&apicex bomber del Pontedera nel vestire la maglia della Salernitana:&lt;em&gt; \"Per me &#34869;na soddisfazione enorme. Fin da quando il Responsabile dell&#146;Area Tecnica Carlo Susini mi ha contattato per la prima volta, speravo con tutto me stesso di poter venire a Salerno. Devo esprimere un ringraziamento particolare a Vittorio Tosto che mi ha sempre parlato benissimo della citt&#2084;i Salerno. Voglio ripetere quanto fatto di buono quest&#146;anno con il Pontedera e ripagare la societ&#2084;ella fiducia che ha riposto nei miei confronti. Non faccio promesse ma posso assicurare i tifosi che suder&#55875;&#56549;mpre la maglia, partita dopo partita, allenamento dopo allenamento\".&lt;/em&gt; Grassi va a rinfoltire il reparto d&apicattacco che - in attesa dell&apicimminente firma sul rinnovo del contratto di Matteo Guazzo - pu&#55874;&#56809;&#2102;antare Ginestra, Gustavo ed il greco Topouzis, che dovrebbe comunque essere ceduto in prestito per garantirgli maggiore minutaggio.",
        "id": "28251",
        "image": "./media/feedgator/images/monthly/2013/06/7_grassi-pontedera.jpg",
        "title_categoria": "Salernitana",
        "title": "Grassi, arriva l&amp;#8217;annuncio della societ&#3744;&amp;#8220;Dar&#55874;&#57126;#8217;anima per questa maglia&amp;#8221;",
        "catid": "24"
    },
    {
        "introtext": "&lt;div&gt;<br><br>&lt;ul&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;a rel=\"nofollow\" href=\"http://redirect.viglink.com?key=11fe087258b6fc0532a5ccfc924805c0&amp;amp;u=http://www.ansa.it/web/notizie/rubriche/cronaca/2013/06/20/Calci-faccia-anziana-rapinarla_8904033.html%23content-corpo\"&gt;salta direttamente al contenuto dell&apicarticolo&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;<br>&lt;li&gt;&lt;a rel=\"nofollow\" href=\"http://redirect.viglink.com?key=11fe087258b6fc0532a5ccfc924805c0&amp;amp;u=http://www.ansa.it/web/notizie/rubriche/cronaca/2013/06/20/Calci-faccia-anziana-rapinarla_8904033.html%23correlati\"&gt;salta al contenuto correlato&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;<br>&lt;/ul&gt;<br>&lt;div&gt;&lt;a rel=\"nofollow\" href=\"http://redirect.viglink.com?key=11fe087258b6fc0532a5ccfc924805c0&amp;amp;u=javascript:document.location%2520=%2520document.location.pathname%2520+%2520&apic?idPhoto=&apic%2520+1\"&gt;&lt;img src=\"media/feedgator/images/monthly/2013/06/8_f33f4c90288e0bc09cd041d310d4f78a.jpg\" alt=\"Calci in faccia a anziana per rapinarla\" title=\"\" /&gt;<br>&lt;/a&gt;<br><br>&lt;/div&gt;<br>&lt;div&gt;&lt;img src=\"media/feedgator/images/monthly/2013/06/8_f33f4c90288e0bc09cd041d310d4f78a.jpg\" alt=\"Calci in faccia a anziana per rapinarla\" /&gt;<br> (ANSA) - GENOVA, 20 GIU - Una donna di 77 anni e&apic stata presa a calci in faccia da un uomo che l&apicha aggredita in casa, E&apic successo a san Fruttuoso, Genova. La donna era appena entrata in casa con la spesa quando il rapinatore le e&apic arrivato alle spalle e l&apicha gettata a terra prendendola a calci in faccia. Ha tentato di strapparle la catenina d&apicoro ma non c&apice&apic riuscito cosi&apic le ha portato via la borsetta e la spesa. L&apicanziana ha dato l&apicallarme: un&apicambulanza l&apicha trasferita in ospedale con varie lesioni al volto.&lt;/div&gt;<br>&lt;/div&gt;",
        "id": "28265",
        "image": "./media/feedgator/images/monthly/2013/06/8_f33f4c90288e0bc09cd041d310d4f78a.jpg",
        "title_categoria": "Cronaca Italia",
        "title": "Calci in faccia a anziana per rapinarla",
        "catid": "25"
    },
    {
        "introtext": "&lt;div&gt;<br>&lt;div&gt;<br>&lt;h5&gt;Storia dell&apicarticolo&lt;/h5&gt;<br>&lt;a rel=\"nofollow\" href=\"http://redirect.viglink.com?key=11fe087258b6fc0532a5ccfc924805c0&amp;amp;u=http://www.ilsole24ore.com/art/notizie/2013-06-20/grecia-pronto-sospendere-aiuti-213601.shtml?uuid=AbaRmw6H\" title=\"\"&gt;Chiudi&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/div&gt;<br>&lt;div&gt;<br>&lt;p&gt;Questo articolo &#34867;tato pubblicato il 20 giugno 2013 alle ore 21:44.&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/p&gt;<br>&lt;/div&gt;<br>&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;<br><br>&lt;p&gt;&lt;img alt=\"Grecia: l&apicFmi minaccia di sospendere gli aiuti ad Atene\" src=\"media/feedgator/images/monthly/2013/06/11_grecia-band-258.jpg\" /&gt;<br>&lt;/p&gt;<br>&lt;p&gt;Un nuovo problema in arrivo per la Grecia. Il Fondo monetario internazionale potrebbe sospendere entro la fine del mese prossimo i pagamenti alla Grecia nell&apicambito della sua partecipazione al piano di salvataggio, a meno che i ministri dell&apiceurozona riuniti a Lussemburgo non impegnino altri fondi. Lo rivela il Financial Times, che cita fonti coinvolte nel programma, secondo cui ci sarebbe da coprire un buco da 3-4 miliardi di euro, una piccola cifra rispetto al totale del piano di aiuti da 172 miliardi di euro finora complessivamente elargiti.&lt;/p&gt;<br>&lt;p&gt;Il gap, sarebbe una conseguenza di due fattori: 1) del rifiuto di alcune banche centrali dei Paesi della zona euro (la Bundsbank? i finlandesi?) di allungare la scadenza dei bond greci che detengono per 3,7 miliardi perch&#38947;onsiderati aiuti per finanziare il debito, vietati dai trattati, e non semplici prestiti; 2) dei ritardi nel piano di privatizzazioni, tra cui l&apicasta andata deserta recentemenete per la vendita del monopolista del gas greco Depa, una cessione a Gazprom da cui Atene sperava di ricavare almeno 900 milioni.&lt;/p&gt;<br><br><br>&lt;p&gt;In ogni caso il gap di 3,7 miliardi si inserisce in un momento di rapporti tesi tra Fmi, sempre pi&#55618;&#56613;ciso ad essere meno politico, e la Ue, che ha respinto le accuse del Fondo sul fatto di aver rallentato nel 2010 la decisione di ristrutturare il debito greco per timore di effetti contagio al resto della zona euro.&lt;/p&gt;<br>&lt;p&gt;Comunque un nuovo esborso di fondi metterebbe in difficolt&#2092;a Germania di Angela Merkel che dovrebbe chiedere al Bundstag un nuovo provvedimento di aiuti ad Atene proprio in vista delle elezioni politiche del 22 settembre.&lt;/p&gt;<br>&lt;p&gt;In serata ad Atene, dopo un incontro tra i partiti della coalizione, la tensione politica &#34868;ornata a salire quando si &#34849;ppreso che Foutis Kouvleis, del partito Dimar, sinistra democratica, ha chiesto di riprendere le trasmissioni della tv pubblica Ert sulla base di alcune garanzie, non trovando per&#55875;&#56686; accordo con il premier Antonis Samaras. Anche il Pasok, il partito socialista, ha minacciato di ritirare l&apicappoggio al partito conservatore, fatto che porterebbe ad elezioni anticipate dopo un solo anno di governo a tre. La situazione in serata era ancora confusa.&lt;/p&gt;<br><br><br><br>&lt;p&gt;&#169;RIPRODUZIONE RISERVATA&lt;/p&gt;<br><br><br><br><br>&lt;p&gt;<br>&lt;/p&gt;&lt;h3&gt;Permalink&lt;/h3&gt;<br>&lt;input /&gt;<br>&lt;/div&gt;",
        "id": "28288",
        "image": "./media/feedgator/images/monthly/2013/06/11_grecia-band-258.jpg",
        "title_categoria": "Ultima Ora",
        "title": "Grecia: l&apicFmi minaccia di sospendere gli aiuti ad Atene",
        "catid": "26"
    }
]
```

When i try to parse it in javascript with `JSON.parse` it gives me unexpected token. What could i do to avoid this? i'm trying to search the solution from 2 days.. 
Thanks!

**EDIT**
Using [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/) and [json.parser.online](http://json.parser.online.fr) i see that they don't give me errors on parsing..

**EDIT1**
This is the `javascriptInterface` from my android application:

```
public void executeQuery(final String query,final String callback) {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>(){
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                DatabaseHandler dbh = new DatabaseHandler(mContext,"myDB");
                dbh.openDataBase();
                Cursor cursor = dbh.executeQuery(query);
                JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
                JSONObject reqObj = new JSONObject();
                while(cursor.moveToNext())
                   reqObj.put( cursor.getColumnName(i),cursor.getString(i));

                array.put(count, reqObj );
                dbh.close();                    
                return array.toString();
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                result = Html.escapeHtml(result);
                result = result.replace("'","&apic");
                result = EncodingUtils.getString(result.getBytes(), "utf-8");
                gap.loadUrl("javascript:"+callback+"('"+result+"');");
            }
        }.execute();
    }
```

And javascript callback:

```
function myCallback(res){
    res = JSON.parse(res); // ERROR HERE
    //...
}
```

You can see error here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Pxzqy/

Comment: [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) says that's perfectly valid JSON, so I'd assume the issue is elsewhere. Can you show us the code where you're passing it to JavaScript and then attempting to parse it?

Comment: Yes, JSONLint says it's ok, but JSONLint doesn't check for every error. It might be coming from your escaped double quotes characters. Couldn't you shorten the JSON and try to parse it piece by piece, to locate the problem more accurately ?

Comment: Please post your code. Could be that the value you are trying to pass to `JSON.parse` is already an object/array (i.e. it is already parsed).

Comment: if the string contains spaces, tabs, and line jumps, it might also not work. Is the full error "Unexpected token ILLEGAL" ?

Comment: i've posted my code and i create a jsfiddle, please see edits

Comment: Okay. So it's huge. So you split in half and see if that gives you an unexpected token. If not, try the other half. Rinse/repeat. Not a 2-day thing.

Comment: *facepalm. Especially not if you should have known enough to notice the unescaped escape slashes. General rule that will help in the future though. Just pass data in JSON. Not HTML. Not stuff that's relevant to JavaScript. Just data. It's so much easier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The correct way to solve this problem would be to correct the server side code to return a valid JSON object. But I will give you the solution for the client side, also.**

---

The problem is that you have some `\n` (new lines) in string.

The error can be shown using this little array (it's the first element, first key, first new lines):

```
var a = '[{"introtext":"\n\n;"}]';

JSON.parse(a);
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Pxzqy/1/)

This is the reason for that the "unexpected token" error is thrown.

[**Replacing `\n` with `\\n` solves**](http://jsfiddle.net/Pxzqy/2/) this error and guides you to next error.

---

## Solution on the client side

The `a` variable will contain your long JSON string that has to be parsed.

> Error: "unexpected token"

1. Replace `\n` with `\\n` and `\r` with `\\r`

   ```
   a = a.replace(/\n/g, "\\n");
   a = a.replace(/\r/g, "\\r");
   ```
2. Replacing `"` with `\"` only in the values, not in keys

   ```
   a = a.replace(/{\\\"/g, "{\"");
   a = a.replace(/\\\":\\\"/g, "\":\"");
   a = a.replace(/\\\",\\\"/g, "\",\"");
   a = a.replace(/\\\"}/g, "\"}");
   ```

---

The final code is:

```
// replace \n and \r with \\n and \\r
a = a.replace(/\n/g, "\\n");
a = a.replace(/\r/g, "\\r");

// replace \" with \\\"
a = a.replace(/\"/g, "\\\"");

// replace again quotes for keys
a = a.replace(/{\\\"/g, "{\"");
a = a.replace(/\\\":\\\"/g, "\":\"");
a = a.replace(/\\\",\\\"/g, "\",\"");
a = a.replace(/\\\"}/g, "\"}")
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Pxzqy/3/)

Comment: nothing... now the error is: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token n `

Comment: before answer, have you tried your solution inside my problem?

Comment: @JackTurky There are multiple reasons, this is one of them. Replace the "\n" with "\\n" and see the result: http://jsfiddle.net/Pxzqy/2/

Comment: @JackTurky You see, your problem is solved "unexpected token" disappeared. So, why downvote?

Comment: as you can see, in my json string there aren't \n because i replace it with <br>.. the problem is the \" that i need to replace with \\"

Comment: @JackTurky I've take time to solve it this morning. Finalmente! See the edited answer. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much!!!!!!!!!! finally that is the solution.. thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you  :)

Comment: @JackTurky Finalmente! :-) You are welcome.

Answer (score -1):

Without having any more context on which I can base an answer, my suggestion would be you use this instead:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Good luck with it.

Comment: That uses `JSON.parse` internally if available. So it would not make a difference.

Comment: Sounds logic. However I have found it does, for instance, in IE. JSON.parse would not work, but jQuery.parseJSON did it.

Comment: That would be the "if available" part; in older versions of browsers that don't have `JSON.parse` jQuery is going to do its own parsing, but that's not the case here - `JSON.parse` *is* available in their browser, so jQuery is just going to use that.

Comment: I see... thanks for the input, I wasn't aware of that.

But still, that could solve the problem, because maybe OP is using a browser that lacks JSON.parse. I understand it is strongly recommended to use jQuery.parseJSON to solve cases like this one?
The error message he says he has is the one IE7 gave me, which I solved this way.

Comment: If `JSON.parse` was not evailable, the error would be different though. Something along the line of `TypeError: cannot call 'parse' of undefined`. But they get a `SyntaxError`. In general your suggestion is good, but not relevant in this situation.